# Should this question be closed: Asking about the Apple iOS framework

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderators, reopen-closed, dupehammer

[This question on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34710251/328397) was force-closed as a duplicate by someone with Gold Badge rights, and I oppose the closure for the following reasons:

- The linked questions are proven "wrong" since [an app](https://www.cyberdust.com//) is able to prevent the capture of a screenshot, even over USB
- Snapchat alerts people that a photo was taken.

It's not too hard to imagine that an Apple-approved OS hook allows this, since both Snapchat and the other app exist on the app store.

I refer to this "OS hook" as an "API". Maybe my choice of words is incorrect (calling it an API) but I need help sussing through the Apple framework to find where to catch this event.

Regarding this ^^ a commenter  said that finding API's are off topic.  The intention for this rule is for finding 3rd party libraries on Github or similar ilk.

**Question**

- Should the question be closed?
- Is rewording possible to re open this question?
- What else should I learn to prevent this kind of hassle in the future?

Comment: It's not that they were a trusted user, they're a gold badge holder.

Comment: @Makoto - Corrected. Thank you, I didn't know where the right came from

Comment: @Paulie_D if the OP adds: [`UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification) is after the fact, is there a notification that fires before this? they should be fine

Comment: The answers to this question seem to address the detection part of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot , but not the prevention part.

Comment: @rene   I edited the question to include Apple's method rene described.

Comment: @Paulie_D: [*"I'm not asking for a 3rd party API, I'm trying to figure out where in the iOS framework this feature/functionality would be."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710251/how-do-i-leverage-uiapplicationuserdidtakescreenshotnotification-to-prevent-scre#comment57194970_34710251) -- Absolutely correct.  Asking for framework guidance is ***not*** a request for an off-site resource.

Answer (score 2):

As the banner specifically tells you, if the answers to the marked duplicate fail to solve your problem, edit the question to explain why the provided solutions don't solve your problem.

Comment: edits made to the question....

Comment: @LamonteCristo then your question is currently in the "reopen" queue. Give it time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the closure was perfectly proper.

The linked question has [an answer that clearly explains how Snapchat achieves this effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680506/603977)*, and it's not clear a) that CyberDust does any differently, or b) [that your assertion about CyberDust is even true](https://www.cyberdust.com/faqs#does-cyber-dust-prevent-screenshots):

> Cyber Dust users on iOS **have the ability to take screenshots** due to **Apple’s** decision to **prevent applications from blocking screenshot** capabilities... [emphasis mine]

I see no reason to not consider this a duplicate. Your edit has not explained why your situation is different; you've merely repeated your earlier statements.

---

*And links to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot) with [even more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/603977).